# Blender only bakes part of material

Tags: image, texture-baking, baking

Blender only bakes part of the material. Using Emit as baking type, if that is of any use.
First picture showing it only bakes the lower part, second picture showing how it should be. What could be some causes of this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please pack your image and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hey! Thanks, but I found the issue, the plane was split into a larger and a smaller surface. For some reason unknown to me blender only baked one part of the surface, the smaller one. After removing the edge that split them, it baked the entire texture. 

but this makes me question how I would bake a texture if the surface is split up?

Comment: it's not a problem to bake with a mesh that have several faces, but the problem may come from the fact that your unwrap is bad, you need to check the UVs to see if they are coherent

Comment: Yes, you are 100% right, this has fixed the issue. Idk how I didn't think of trying that out. And thank you for bringing it to my attention :)

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to unwrap my model. Silly me.

Comment: It is literally the answer to my problem. It was behaving the way it did, because I didn't unwrap the model after changing it.